# Reverse Geocoding for Mapquest SDK on Android

Tags: android, mapbox, reverse-geocoding, mapquest

Is there anyway I can reverse Geocode, I have MapQuest SDK(Android) ?

I know Android has its own GeoCoder but if I have Lat and Lng from Mapquest and when I reverse geocode from AndroidGeocoder (google) the address of the POI differs a bit( door number) .

Let me know if there is any API integrated into Mapquest SDK ?
**NOTE: I don't want make a service call for it. Just if any API already integrated into SDK?**

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Geocoding API which also has reverse geocoding [Here](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/geocoding-api/#reverse).

Comment: NOTE: I don't want make a service call for it. Just if any API already integrated into SDK?

Comment: There are no hooks for the api in the Android sdk (yet). Like Akash mentions, you can hit it directly. I use HttpURLConnection to hit the geocoder after a long click on the map.

Comment: I'm using the same but was looking for the api which is already integrated. Looks like there is none, Thanks.